# Pressing phone back button in one activity goes to another activity that hasn't been initialized before Android

Tags: android, android-activity

This is very different from all of the "similar" questions SO has given me. I am working on an app and when a user signs up an account in one activity called SignUpActivity, I take them to another activity called UserProfileActivity using the following code:

**SignUpActivity:**

```
Intent userProfileIntent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(userProfileIntent);
finish();
```

Now, in UserProfileActivity, if I press the back button, it takes me to an activity that has never been visited/instantiated during the app's lifetime called PartyListActivity.

**UserProfileActivity:**

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

So my question is why, when I press back in UserProfileActivity, does it go back to PartyListActivity, when I have never been on PartyListActivity before? Is there something in the manifest file that dictates this behavior?

**Edit**

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.package">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PartyListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_party_list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UserProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_friends"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: when do you call to PartyListActivity? and please show me your manifest!

Comment: You can use adb to print the acivity backstack `adb shell dumpsys activity package <your.package.name>`

Comment: @redAllocator I make a call to PartyListActivity in other methods. But those methods are never called in the situation I am reproducing. And AyushKhare when would I run that?

Comment: pelase upload your manifest.xml

Comment: @Michael you run it when you are in your UserProfileActivity

Comment: @AyushKhare So I ran the command while in UserProfileActivity and I searched through the file for PartyListActivity but couldn't find any references to it.

Comment: Have you ever called your PartyListActivity using intend for PartyListActivity but when I press back in UserProfileActivity, does it go back to PartyListActivity? really?

Comment: @redAllocator can you clarify your question I'm not getting what you're asking

Comment: Have you ever called your PartyListActivity ?

Comment: No I have not called it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try my best to break the stuff and follow the activity flow:

- Your **launching** as well as **root** activity is `LoginActivity`
  ( From your `manifest` file).
- Then, from `LoginActivity`  you entered to `SignUpActivity`, either with some UI action or programmatically (Assuming the  `LoginActivity` is not finished).
- From `SignUpActivity` you entered to `UserProfileActivity`. (Finishing the `SignUpActivity` i.e. `SignUpActivity` is removed from back stack).
- Now you're in `UserProfileActivity` and pressing back button from there takes you to `LoginActivity` because `SignUpActivity` was already removed from back stack.
- But you said, you're in `PartyListActivity` which can happen only if you start it programmatically from `LoginActivity`.

> Look in your  **LoginActivity** , the unexpected activity is starting from there.

More about [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Comment: That's exactly it.. I return from my activity to login activity. Then it checks if I'm still signed into Gmail. If I am, it launches the intent to start PartyListActivity. I haven't tried it but that should exactly what's causing this problem. I'll accept the answer soon! thanks

Comment: Destroying the `LoginActivity` after starting `PartyListActivity` in `LoginActivity` might solve your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a "parentActivityName" attribute in the definition of an activity in AndroidManifest.xml.  Do you have such an attribute in the definition of your SignUpActivity?

Full documentation of this attribute and other information around back stack navigation is available at https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I read I think you're saying to set a parentActivityName to either exit the app or go to PartyListActivity? Either way I don't want to manually set that. If I'm in UserProfileActivity and all of the activities leading to that one used `finish()` I want to know why PartyListActivity is in the backstack when I press the back button.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 :** It doesn't make sense that PartyListActivity is launching after UserProfileActivity is finished. Somewhere somehow you configured or calling to that activity. Double check your codes.

**Option 2 :** try to finish UserProfileActivity activity itself onBackPress() (even it will finish)

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```